# jQuery Auto complete issue

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Hi guys i am encountering jquery auto complete problem. Actually, in the example given by developers is working fine but once i am trying to implement into my system it is not working;

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='scripts/jquery.autocomplete.js'></script></code>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="scripts/jquery.autocomplete.css" />

<script type="text/javascript">

$().ready(function() {

    jQuery("#coursex").autocomplete("get_course_list.php", {
        width: 260,
        matchContains: true,
        selectFirst: false
    });

});

</script>
<form autocomplete="off">
        <p>
            Course Namexx <label>:</label>

            <input type="text" name="course" id="coursex" />

            <!--input type="button" value="Get Value" /-->
        </p>

        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

The problem is that I am not getting any javascript error in firebug and all the files are included. ajax-autocomplete project. you may download from the net.

Any suggestions how to debug, how to solve or any other product without jquery only ajax and css.

Comment: Have you included jquery and jquery-ui?

Comment: yes, I include jquery but they did not include in the original example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hiya see **demo here** please: http://jsfiddle.net/Xzy9T/

please include Jquery ui (like in example) as well & Please make sure that the src of you you javascripts are correct or you can find one online and add the reference.

**HTML**

```
   <p>

        Course Namexx <label>:</label>

        <input type="text" name="course" id="coursex" />

        <!--input type="button" value="Get Value" /-->

    </p>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
​
```

**Jquery**

```
$( "#coursex" ).autocomplete({
    source: function( req, resp ) {
        $.post( "/echo/json/", {
            json: '["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]',
            delay: 1
        }, function(data) {
            resp( data );
        }, "JSON" );
    }
});
​
```

[image]

Comment: No, actually, it is not working if I apply only to this system any other system is working well. I tried to debug line by line and I found that it stop to only when I tried to load  "phpGrid". But I don't what is the exact problem. Firebug doesn't show anything. Can you suggestmi something else. Thanks

Comment: Is there any other auto completion you can suggestion without jquery

Comment: Hiya @AkramYakubov hows it man? hmm let me see - Jquery auto complete: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete is pretty saweet, you might find few other versions in google; **LIKE This** : http://www.devbridge.com/projects/autocomplete/jquery/ - (I will see if I can find some); WHats wrong with auto complete you are using bro, :) have a nice one, cheerios!